# error cp: cannot overwrite directory '/usr/bin/dpkg' with non-directory

Tags: dpkg

Go to this url http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/
and you will see a list of `dpkg` packages. You need to find the `dpkg` version you need than open new terminal.

Anywhere your machine I select Desktop.

```
mkdir dpkg 
cd dpkg
```

Run:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/
```

(Add the version of dpkg you need after the last `/`)

For example I needed `dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb` but this does not exist any more so I chose the closest one which is

```
dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb
```

So:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb
```

Run

```
ar x dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb
```

Now you can see the contents:

```
~/dpkg $ ls
control.tar.gz  data.tar.gz  debian-binary  dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb
```

Run

```
~/dpkg $ tar xfvz data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg
./usr/bin/dpkg
~/dpkg $ ls
control.tar.gz  data.tar.gz  debian-binary  dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.8_amd64.deb  usr
~/dpkg $ cd usr/bin/
~/dpkg/usr/bin $ ls
dpkg

~/dpkg/usr/bin $ sudo cp dpkg /usr/bin/
```

Hi after performing all the above steps it is giving me an error
cp: cannot overwrite directory '/usr/bin/dpkg' with non-directory

Got this error after last step
What can be this error?

Comment: Why are you messing with `dpkg`? You are aware that this is a vital part of the system?

Comment: I think you somehow messed up by creating the dir `/usr/bin/dpkg` instead of `./usr/bin/dpkg`. I find that guide very confusing, and I don't see the point of it...

Comment: Also where are these steps from? Can you provide a link to the source?

Comment: By mistake i removed dpkg, that is the reason i am doing this.

Comment: Ok. Please state the version of Ubuntu you're running. Then find the matching version of dpkg.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site.   *Your `dpkg` package isn't for a supported release of Ubuntu*

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: @ArturMeinild I am using 22.04LTS version of Ubuntu